# Native Time Picker / Text Area freezes page only with iOS7 on iPhone 4S! (HTML/javascript app)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios7

I've got a question that I haven't been able to get answered anywhere.

We are developing a mobile app in HTML/JavaScript, and we came across an issue only with iOS7 AND iPhone 4S (but not with iPhone 5). Whenever there is an interactive field where we bring in a native element - e.g. a time picker or text area - pressing the native next/previous buttons cause the page to get "stuck" when done. As in, when the native element (time picker or keyboard) comes up, it pushes the page up like it's supposed to, but then when finished the page doesn't come back down (such that the user cannot reach header buttons necessary to continue using the app).

What's going on, and how do we fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There are some nasty iOS7 issues with web sites and web apps: http://www.sencha.com/blog/the-html5-scorecard-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-in-ios7/